# cannot use r.Condition.AgeInDays (variable of type int64) as type *int64 in struct literal

Tags: firebase, go, fibers

when i import firebase to golang file, i see this bug.
I'm a newbie, learning to Golang, please help me to fix them
**my code:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "firebase.google.com/go"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

func helloWorld(c *fiber.Ctx)  {
    c.Send("Hello World")
}

func main()  {
    //connect db
    sa := option.WithCredentialsFile("./webgolang.json")
    app, err := firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), nil, sa)
    client, err := app.Firestore(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    //
    app := fiber.New()
    app.Get("/", helloWorld)
    setupRoutes(app)

    app.Listen(4000)
}
```

**it's bug**

```
C:\Users\HP\go\pkg\mod\cloud.google.com\go\storage@v1.22.1\bucket.go:1504:30: cannot use r.Condition.AgeInDays (variable of type int64) as type *int64 in struct literal
C:\Users\HP\go\pkg\mod\cloud.google.com\go\storage@v1.22.1\bucket.go:1592:30: cannot use rr.Condition.Age (variable of type *int64) as type int64 in struct literal
```

Comment: Please work through the Tour of Go https://go.dev/tour/welcome/1 for basic syntac and working with pointers. Try `&r.Condition.AgeInDays`.

Comment: You have mismatched versions in your dependencies. Your version of cloud.google.com/gs/storage (v1.22.1) does not work with the version of google.golang.org/api/storage/v1 that you're using (but that we cannot see)

Answer (score 8):

Upgrade the cloud storage version to v1.26.0, so if you go to your `go.mod` file, you should have this:

```
cloud.google.com/go/storage v1.26.0 // indirect
```

Comment: Had to use `v1.27.0` as of Sep 24, 2022